# Typesetting Quine quotes

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, amssymb

The obvious way of typesetting Quine quotes, also known as [quasi-quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-quotation), in LaTeX doesn't work well when the content of the quote is tall. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\ulcorner \frac{1}{2} \right\urcorner
\]
\end{document}
```

This seems odd, given that `\ulcorner` (resp. `\urcorner`) is in the `mathopen` (resp. `mathclose`) class. Is there some way of getting LaTeX to automatically raise the quotes to match the height of the content?

**Edit.** I forgot to mention that I would very much prefer a solution that works with `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 8):

For good results `\left` and `\right` need support at font level for their delimiters. For example, `MnSymbol` supports resizable corners:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\ulcorner \frac{1}{2} \right\urcorner
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

However, loading `MnSymbol` also affects the appearance of other math symbols.

The following example only uses the relevant part of MnSymbol to get the two corner symbols:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12
}{}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\ulcorner}
    {\mathopen}{MnLargeSymbols}{'036}{MnLargeSymbols}{'036}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\urcorner}
    {\mathclose}{MnLargeSymbols}{'043}{MnLargeSymbols}{'043}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\left\ulcorner \frac{1}{2} \right\urcorner
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using `unicode-math`, so `MnSymbol` is not even an option for me.

Comment: What is required to obtain the other two corners \llcorner and \lrcorner?

Comment: @flamingpenguin An editor with the ability to replace `\ulcorner` by `\llcorner` and `\urcorner` by `\lrcorner` :-)

Comment: I changed `\urcorner` to `\lrcorner` but it nevertheless typesets as a urcorner.

Comment: @EvanAad Changing the name for a thing does not change the thing. The correct declaration for `\lrcorner` can be found in `TDS:tex/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.sty`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this was a long time ago, but how about using Sam Buss's macro that is supposed to work for Gödel numbers. See http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/symbols/corner-quotes-for-godel-numbers/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\newbox\qqBoxA
\newdimen\qqCornerHgt
\setbox\qqBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\qqCornerHgt=\ht\qqBoxA
\newdimen\qqArgHgt
\def\Quinequote #1{%
    \setbox\qqBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
    \qqArgHgt=\ht\qqBoxA%
    \ifnum     \qqArgHgt<\qqCornerHgt \qqArgHgt=0pt%
    \else \advance \qqArgHgt by -\qqCornerHgt%
    \fi \raise\qqArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\qqBoxA %
    \raise\qqArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}


\begin{document}
    \[
    \Quinequote{\frac{1}{2}}
    \] 
\end{document}
```

Results in [image]

Answer (score 3):

The `scalerel` package can stretch or scale the symbols, but that may not be what you want.  On the other hand, if the quotes are just shifted, is the meaning unambiguous, or could the quotes be misiniterpreted to apply to the numerator only?  (I don't know how they are used).  Otherwise, if just shifting is acceptable, use `\atop`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\stretchleftright{\ulcorner}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}{\urcorner}
\]

\[
\scaleleftright{\ulcorner}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}{\urcorner}
\]

\[
{\ulcorner \atop \phantom{2}} \frac{1}{2} {\urcorner \atop \phantom{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works in `unicode-math`, though the results are ugly. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It may be ugly in code, but this mess

```
\newlength{\tmplenA}
\newlength{\tmplenB}

\newcommand{\ucorner}[1]{\settowidth{\tmplenA}{$\ulcorner$}
\settoheight{\tmplenB}{$#1$}
\setlength{\tmplenB}{1.1\tmplenB}
\addtolength{\tmplenB}{-\tmplenA}
\raisebox{\tmplenB}{$\ulcorner$}\hspace{-0.5\tmplenA}
#1
\hspace{-0.5\tmplenA}\raisebox{\tmplenB}{$\urcorner$}}
```

will let you produce

```
$\ucorner{P}$\\\\
$\ucorner{\frac{1}{2}}$\\\\
$\ucorner{\left(x^{x^x}\right)}$
```

[image: LaTeX output]

To adjust the height of the corner brackets upwards, replace the 1.1s with something greater than 1.1.  To adjust the brackets inwards, replace the 0.5s with something greater than 0.5 (but keep the negative on the second one).

Comment: Why do you subtract the width of the quasi-quotation mark from 1.1x the height of the argument in #1? What does width has to do with height? See "\addtolength{\tmplenB}{-\tmplenA}".

Comment: How to make the text within the ucorners wrap to the next line?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little easier and a lot sketchier.

The symbols appear as accents in the `tipa` package (which works in textmode), so when used as punctuation they had questionable spacing, which I modified using equally questionable methods:

```
\usepackage{tipa}

\newcommand{\lquine}{\textopencorner\hspace{-1pt}}
\newcommand{\rquine}{$\,$\textcorner$\ $}
```